# Can't submit the form unless I reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error in browser, and the select tags are  not showing unless I reload.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (VM2264 items:1)
```

In order to manage returns of my online shop I have the following:

- I have a html table where are listed the items I bought with there
  quantity.
- In this table (where each line represent a form) I can select specific items to return in this list with a check
  box
- If the item quantity is greater than 1, (for example 3) then after checking it a select tag appears with the possibility to choose  the quantity to return  1, 2, 3...

This form(table) is in the Item index

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <% @items.each do |item|%>
            <tr>

                <td><%= image_tag item.order_item.variant.product.attachments.first.url, class: "small_image" %></td>
                <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.order_item.variant.product.title %> 
                    <br>
                    <%= item.order_item.variant.product.color %>
                </td>
                <td><%= item.order_item.variant.size %></td>
                <td><%= number_to_currency_euro item.order_item.variant.product.price %></td>


                <%= form_with model: @item, method: :patch, remote: true, html: { class: "update-form"} do |f| %>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: item.id %>
                    <% if item.quantity <= 1 %>
                        <% if item.selected == true %>
                            <td><%= f.check_box :selected, { checked: true, value: item.selected, class: 'form-control return_check', onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %>  </td>
                            <td></td>
                        <% else %>
                            <td><%= f.check_box :selected, { checked: false, value: item.selected, class: 'form-control return_check', onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %> </td>
                            <td></td>
                    <% end %>
                  <% else %>
                        <% if item.selected == true %>
                            <td class="mulitple-item"><%= f.check_box :selected, { checked: true, value: item.selected, class: 'form-control', onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %></td>
                            <td><%= f.select :quantity, options_for_select((0..item.quantity), selected: 2), {}, { class: 'form-control select-qty' } %></td>

                            <td><%= f.submit "Valider le nombre", class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm valid_return select-" %></td>
                        <% else %>
                            <td><%= f.check_box :selected, { checked: false, value: item.selected, class: 'form-control return_check', id:"return_check", onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %></td> 
                            <td></td>
                        <% end %>                           
                    <% end %>   
                <% end %>

            </tr>

        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to "Continuer le retour",  edit_clients_order_returning_path(@order, @returning), class: "btn btn-main btn-block" %>
```

I have this js script that display the select tag if checkboxe is checked

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

        $('.valid_return').click(function(){
            alert("Are you sure?");

                this.form.submit();

        });

    function checkAll(checktoggle){
        var checkboxes = new Array(); 
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('return_check');

        checkboxes.forEach(function(boxe){
            boxe.onClick(function(){
                for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                    alert(checkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display);
                    checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
                };
                };

            });
        });
        }
    });
```

How could I fix this?
Also do you have any suggestion to improve this big form ?

Comment: Just a guess, but to me it looks like the problem is ```onchange: 'this.form.submit();' ``` inside your HTML / your templates. Try to remove it and look if the error still occurs. Otherwise, remove the ```this.form.submit()``` part in your JS and check again. It should be either of these.

Comment: Without this I can't submit my forms...

Comment: @David Er... I think the whole point is to submit the form after the alert. Although an `alert` is completely useless for this; you'd want a confirmation dialog and submit or not based on that.

Comment: @DaveNewton By looking at the error, it seems like the problem comes from the ```<input>``` elements. That's why I suggested to remove the ```onchange``` part and see if the error keeps occuring.

Comment: The error occurs when I check the boxe...

Comment: @David Yes, it's clear that's where the error is coming from (yay turbolinks). Obviously removing it will stop the error :/

Comment: I agree that if I remove it it fix it but it's not user friendly to have to many button to press... 
Also I do agree for the alert ( it was for a test shoud not have posted it)

Comment: Check your rendered HTML and ensure it's what you think it should be. I don't see any immediate reason this shouldn't work. While you're at it maybe refactor out some of the duplicated code--it's harder to think about when you have to read each line carefully to understand there aren't many differences.

Comment: @johan If the form is intended to save itself "automagically" then a submit button is redundant. UX is subjective, but it should always be consistent, e.g., two submit mechanisms (one hidden, one visible) could be misleading/confusing.

Comment: @johan Having a form which can't be submitted isn't very user friendly either, is it? There's no point in clinging to something which doesn't work. Also, I doubt you need any additional mechanism (except for specific reasons not pointed out in your question) to "automatically" save the state of the form. If a user changes any of your form controls, the form automatically has the state of what is currently set per control. It's very annoying to have a form, check a single checkbox in it and watch the whole thing reload. As said, there might be a specific reason but currently I can't see why

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the list of items could be long, and if he has  10 items to check and submit then it becomes redundant...
The page after is a summary of the items he is returning ( the checked ones).

Comment: @David It's a remote form; processing happens behind the scenes. Lots of forms/apps do this--you just need UX to indicate as much. There's no "reloading" on a remote form, which is why you need additional UX so the user understands it's saving as changed. It can also complicate the back end. Ultimately it's a *better* UX, but has to be handled with care. As an example, consider a shopping cart that allows deletion of items: the deletes happen "in place", you don't move off the page. A submit (that isn't a link like "Update Cart") would be *more* disruptive.

Comment: Well I added my whole table maybe it would help  to understand  the problem

Comment: This is exactly the idea of the shopping cart  just that I select the items I want to send back

Comment: @DaveNewton OK, this makes sense. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: Try to give your forms an id and submit it by identifying your form from the root of document: document.getElementById("form_id").submit()

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ... your code
```

to this:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    ... your code
```

The `turbolinks:load` event may be fired before jQuery gets initialized, you should always listend to that event on the document, not via jquery.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but ther eis still the same error